# Calculating bandwidth #2

Tags: c#

I was successfully calculate bandwidth consumed by my application (which connects to web service to send files) using [this][1]
  [1]: [Calculating Bandwidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442409) i used the code provided by Rasmus Faber... One thing puzzled me: the received bytes is far too more than sent bytes... As far as i am concerned i am sending images, xml files etc and returning error codes.. therefore the sent bytes should be more? ....

Answer (score 1):

I would look at what I was sending over the wire using either [System.Net](http://blogs.msdn.com/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/471003.aspx) tracing or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org). This will tell you exactly what's happening in your calls.