# internet usage in every application

Tags: c#, networking

i would like to ask how can i get the internet amount that being used by some application like streaming and etc. i would like to make a program using in C# and i don't how can i start it.... give some advice thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to measure the bandwidth usage of a given application?

Answer (score 3):

As a starting point I'd look at the [WinSock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. You may find a way of pulling traffic information on a per process basis.
If you want to see total network usage, I'd use the Performance Monitoring tools. I found this example from a [web search](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/5478-How-Show-Network-Traffic-using-C-dot.aspx):

```
private static void ShowNetworkTraffic()
{
     PerformanceCounterCategory performanceCounterCategory = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");
     string instance = performanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames()[0]; // 1st NIC !
     PerformanceCounter performanceCounterSent = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", instance);
     PerformanceCounter performanceCounterReceived = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", instance);

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("bytes sent: {0}k\tbytes received: {1}k", performanceCounterSent.NextValue() / 1024, performanceCounterReceived.NextValue() / 1024);
         Thread.Sleep(500);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, there exists no standard method to measure network bandwidth per-application. The most you can get with standard means is essentially what `netstat` and `perfmon` show. The only way to calculate per-application metrics is to write an NDIS filter driver, or use an existing filter driver such as WinPcap. But both ways you'll have to install a driver on every target machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [How to calculate network bandwidth speed in c#](http://www.m0interactive.com/archives/2008/02/06/how_to_calculate_network_bandwidth_speed_in_c_/)

**EDIT**

Now that I understand the question better try looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442409/c-bandwidth) other SO question

Comment: That article specifies how to show bandwith data for the entire computer (or rather network interface), not for a single application.

Comment: Klaus Byskov Hoffmann - yes that what i mean.. sorry for bad english.