# Performance Monitor .NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0 Instance naming

Tags: c#, .net, windows, naming, performancecounter

I'm trying to use a Performance Counter do determine how many bytes my application has sent or received. I followed the suggested solution found here: [Calculating Bandwidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442409/c-bandwidth), but the instance of my application doesn’t show up in the “.NET CLR Networking” category. Exception message:

> "Instance 'ApplicationName[8824]' does not exist in the specified
>   Category"

(I have added `<performanceCounters enabled="true"/>` in my App.config and it still it cannot be found after some networking activities)

So I started Performance Monitor so see the error with my own eyes. As expected, my application doesn't show up in the *.NET CLR Networking* category, but it can luckily be found in the *.NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0* category.

However, my problem is that I cannot figure out how instance name is generated. Here is the name of the instance I see in the Performance  Monitor: `ApplicationName.exe_p4952_r15_ad1`.

So far I have figured out that the first parts must be made of **ProcessName** and **PID**, but I 
have no clue what the last two (**"r15"** and **"ad1"**) pieces come from.

Does somebody have a clue what the last two pieces could be?

One solution would be to enumerate all the instances found in the “.NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0” category and search for ApplicationName.exe_PID*, but would prefer to look for the correct name directly (if possible).

Comment: Did you get this to work? I can't seem to get any values from the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537616.aspx) for more information on how the name is built. In short the "rXX" is the runtime ID of the common language runtime (instance) that executes your code.

This new naming convention was established so that in side-by-side scenarios (where you have more than one CLR instance in a process; which is a new feature starting with .NET 4.0) you can actually differentiate the performance counters.

The "adXX" is not described on the page above, but from the acronym I'd suppose it stands for Application Domain. The number could possibly be the [AppDomain.Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.id.aspx) of the application domain.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10329252) on how to get the correct name. In short, use

```
var processFileName = Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
var instanceName = VersioningHelper.MakeVersionSafeName(processFileName, ResourceScope.Machine, ResourceScope.AppDomain);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
string appDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName.ToLower();
string a = VersioningHelper.MakeVersionSafeName(appDomain, ResourceScope.Machine, ResourceScope.AppDomain);
```

I've had problems with version with process name when writing unit tests. Version with app domain works for tests and for applications result was the same as with process name.