# Getting bytes sent/received of the current application

Tags: c#

I found this [snippet](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0580__Network/ReportinformationfromNetworkInterfacenetworkstatistics.htm)

Won't that show the total bytes sent/received from my network? I'm looking the stats of the current application only.

Edit: Any more help? Can't seem to get the bytes sent/received for 1 application.

Comment: It appears to be limited to a single interface and IPv4 traffic only.  If you have more than one interface, or use IPv6, then it won't show all of the traffic.  And, being documented by Microsoft, you are left guessing at exactly what bytes are being counted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442409/calculating-bandwidth

Comment: The answer to you question might be in here: [Retrieve process network usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026204/retrieve-process-network-usage)