# How to monitor the network bandwidth usage of a specific application?

Tags: c#, performance, performancecounter

I am trying to learn how to monitor the network bandwidth usage of a specific application.  I am looking at `IPv4InterfaceStatistics`, but that seems to monitor an NIC card's performance.
I'd like to monitor a specific application to see how much bandwidth is consumed every second.
Does anyone know of an example of how this can be done?

Comment: Resource Monitor for Windows.

Comment: @DeepakMishra I asume he wants to resolve this programatically, since it is C# and stack, not serverfault, but i could be wrong.

Comment: Yes I want to resolve this programatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442409/calculating-bandwidth/442459#442459

Comment: Network Performance Counters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70xadeyt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: the above link should answer your question..

Comment: can you please provide me an example @DeepakMishra

Comment: @Manish: let me know if that doesn't work

Comment: It shows that Instance does not exist in the specified category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var bytesSentPerformanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
                bytesSentPerformanceCounter.CategoryName = ".NET CLR Networking";
                bytesSentPerformanceCounter.CounterName = "Bytes Sent";
                bytesSentPerformanceCounter.InstanceName = GetInstanceName();
                bytesSentPerformanceCounter.ReadOnly = true;

                var bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
                bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.CategoryName = ".NET CLR Networking";
                bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.CounterName = "Bytes Received";
                bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.InstanceName = GetInstanceName();
                bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.ReadOnly = true;

                Console.WriteLine("Bytes sent: {0}", bytesSentPerformanceCounter.RawValue);
                Console.WriteLine("Bytes received: {0}", bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.RawValue);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        private static string GetInstanceName()
        {
            string returnvalue = "not found";
          //Checks bandwidth usage for CUPC.exe..Change it with your application Name
            string applicationName = "CUPC"; 
                PerformanceCounterCategory[] Array = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();
            for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Array[i].CategoryName.Contains(".NET CLR Networking"))
                    foreach (var item in Array[i].GetInstanceNames())
                    {
                        if (item.ToLower().Contains(applicationName.ToString().ToLower()))
                            returnvalue = item;

                    }

            }
            return returnvalue;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified version using PerformanceCounter:

```
var processFileName = Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
var bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.CategoryName = ".NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0";
bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.CounterName = "Bytes Received";
bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.InstanceName = VersioningHelper.MakeVersionSafeName(processFileName, ResourceScope.Machine, ResourceScope.AppDomain);
bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.ReadOnly = true;

Console.WriteLine("Bytes received: {0}", bytesReceivedPerformanceCounter.RawValue);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are familiar with the OSI model http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model you see that you try to interact with layer 3 where you should be interacting with layer 7.

I your connection with what ever class you are using you are able to measure bytes sent, specially if you are transporting the individual bytes, (this is since i have no idea how your code is looking), you should be able to calculate the amount of bytes over a time divide with number of seconds and you will have your result.