# How can I use System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter to track the bandwidth usage for a process?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get some of the values that are in the windows 7 resource monitor. In particular,I have found the memory usage and cpu but i am not able to get the bandwidth per process. I've looked into the PerformanceCounter class and I don't see a way to drill down to the process network level. The resource monitor has exactly what I am looking for. I looked into WMI as well and it seems most people recommend not using it but if anyone has WMI query as well then please let me know.
One most important thing that i want to tell you is that i don't want to get the calculated bandwidth of Network Interface , I want per process as shown in the resource monitor of the task manager.

So does anyone know how I can get this statistics at the process level using .net classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to monitor the network bandwidth usage of a specific application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396786/how-to-monitor-the-network-bandwidth-usage-of-a-specific-application), but note that the *accepted* answer does not seem particularly useful; instead look below it.

Comment: You can see that my question is different and there is no answer of bandwidth use by process @NathanTuggy

Comment: Honestly, I couldn't; they seemed pretty similar to me, but admittedly that was a fairly quick look. Explain why they aren't the same, when the second answer specifically filters by a given process and measures in/out bandwidth?

Comment: actually when i am using that example for application chrome.exe , i got the error as Instance does not exist in the specified category.

Comment: "Instance does not exist " because chrome.exe isn't .net application

Comment: Then how can i know the bandwidth use by chrome @Sohanty