# C# Measure bandwidth of a specific application

Tags: c#, performancecounter, system.diagnostics

I need to measure the bandwidth of an application I've made. Let's say that this application is called `myapp.exe`.

I have made a library called `BandwidthMonitor` (BM) which is called from within `myapp.exe`. `myapp.exe` periodically calls `BM.Measure()` which returns a `BandwidthMeasurement`.

My `BM` looks like this:

```
public class BandwidthMonitor
{
    PerformanceCounter bandwidthCounter;
    PerformanceCounter dataReceivedCounter;
    PerformanceCounter dataSentCounter;

    List<float> byetsSent = new List<float>();
    List<float> byetsReceived = new List<float>();
    List<float> byetsUtilization = new List<float>();

    float bandwidth;
    int ticks = 0;

    static string categoryName = ".NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0";

    public BandwidthMonitor()
    {
        try
        {

            bandwidthCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
            bandwidthCounter.CategoryName = categoryName;
            bandwidthCounter.CounterName = "Current Bandwidth";
            bandwidthCounter.InstanceName = instance;
            bandwidthCounter.ReadOnly = true;

            dataReceivedCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
            dataReceivedCounter.CategoryName = categoryName;
            dataReceivedCounter.CounterName = "Bytes Received/sec";
            dataReceivedCounter.InstanceName = instance;
            dataReceivedCounter.ReadOnly = true;

            dataSentCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
            dataSentCounter.CategoryName = categoryName;
            dataSentCounter.CounterName = "Bytes Sent/sec";
            dataSentCounter.InstanceName = instance;
            dataSentCounter.ReadOnly = true;

            Console.WriteLine("Bandwidth monitor ready.");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    public BandwidthMeasurement Measure()
    {
        var measurement = new BandwidthMeasurement();
        ticks++;

        try
        {
            var bytesSent = dataSentCounter.RawValue;
            var bytesReceived = dataReceivedCounter.RawValue;

            measurement.BytesSent = bytesSent;
            measurement.ByesReceived = bytesReceived;

            double utilization = (8 * (bytesSent + bytesReceived)) / (bandwidth * ticks) * 100;

            measurement.Utilization = utilization;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }


        return measurement;
    }

    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/27418721/596841
    private static string GetInstanceName()
    {
        string returnvalue = "not found";
        //Checks bandwidth usage for CUPC.exe..Change it with your application Name
        string applicationName = "myapp";
        PerformanceCounterCategory[] Array = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories();
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Array[i].CategoryName.Contains(categoryName))
                foreach (var item in Array[i].GetInstanceNames())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                    if (item.ToLower().Contains(applicationName.ToString().ToLower()))
                        returnvalue = item;
                }

        }
        return returnvalue;
    }
}
```

For some reason, `GetInstanceName()` always returns `not found`. I cannot figure out why.

**I've tried:**

- settings `categoryName` to `.NET CLR Networking`
- passing `myapp` `processId` to the `BM` and looking up the category.
- delaying the point at which `BM` is instantiated so as to ensure `myapp` is fully loaded and operational first (pretty pointless, I think, but I don't know what else to try... grasping at straws here!).

```
PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory(".NET CLR Networking  4.0.0.0"); // and without the 4.0.0.0
var instanceNames = category.GetInstanceNames().Where(i => i.Contains(string.Format("p{0}", processId)));

if (instanceNames.Count() == 0) throw new Exception("Instance name not found");
```

Passing the processId does not find the instance name, either.

I keep getting the exception:

> Could not locate performance counter with specified category name ".NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0".

What am I doing wrong?