# Calculate only internet usage in C#

Tags: c#, network-interface

I am working on a Internet usage meter that calculate daily internet usage in pc.
I was used below code to read data up and down.

```
NetworkInterface nic = nicArr[0]; //select internet connected Interface

IPv4InterfaceStatistics interfaceStats = nic.GetIPv4Statistics();

lblBytesReceived.Text = interfaceStats.BytesReceived.ToString(); //DOWNLOAD
lblBytesSent.Text = interfaceStats.BytesSent.ToString();  //UPLOAD
```

It is working well with a PC that not connected to a local network. But when it is working on computers that connected to local network, then byte transferred between local computers also added to internet usage.(If I copy files to network pc, then it also calculated) but I need to filter only data transferred for internet use.  How can i do this ?

Comment: Did you have done some research on the subject?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating Bandwidth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442409/calculating-bandwidth)